# Reordering an ordered list

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a following SQL table with data

```
ProductList 
id  order productname
79   1     name1
42   2     name2
67   3     somename
88   4     othername
99   5     XYZ
66   6     ABC
```

Display order is very volatile, it will change frequently, users will add or remove items and reorder the items.

How should i handle this situation without updating multiple records. Example: if user enters a new product between 1 and 2 order, i do not want to update the order of all the records beneath 2 and if someone switch order 3 to 4 i don't want to update every record under 3.

Comment: no  scheduled task to 'reorder' the order, it has to be in realtime.

Comment: Like Will A says - start with values with a long distance between them. When you have to insert something in between, insert it half way between the values in question. Maybe once a month, change all the records back to steps of a 100 or so. No reordering necessary.

Comment: my suggestion for a scheduled task is to have a scheduled 'maintenance' task that runs during a quiet period - to set the order values back to something 'cleaner'.

Comment: What prevents you from using several updates, and a transaction around them? You're not even in [READ COMMITTED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) isolation? Also, what's *frequently* is in *it will change frequently?*?

Comment: Some databases (like SQL Server) will allow you to calculate row numbers on the fly. Would that be enough? Being able to calculate row numbers (using the ROW_NUMBER() function) at query time? If not, you might be able to update that table periodically, say every hour, by running such a query and updating the "order" column - would that be good enough (have the table updated once every hour or so)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the 'orrible old trick made famous(?) by old BASIC coders - set your orders to be 100, 200, 300, 400 etc. and then you can pick an order 'inbetween' when you need to.  This could get messy - and if you're anticipating a lot of reordering then I'd recommend that you have a scheduled task to 'reorder' the order values every now and then for the entire table.

Comment: Problem with the scheduled task - the old order will be in place till the job executes.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - How would this be a problem?  My take is that the order value is for display purposes only - if it's being used as the primary key end of a foreign key anywhere then all bets are off.

Comment: @Ponies: I think the scheduled task is not to change the actual ordering, but to reset the numbers to be separated by 100 so that you don't run into a situation in which all the intermediate numbers have been filled up.

Answer (score 5):

A second answer to the same question:

Use a DOUBLE field for ordering and split the difference between the two values you want to insert between.   In any standard business application, I doubt very, very much whether you'll ever approach the number of inserts beyond which you cannot resolve the sort order difference.

Comment: Actually you will pretty fast. If an 8 byte number is used in 8 * 8 = 64 reorders in the same position.

Comment: @BorisYankov it is worse than 64 because a [typical double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation) uses 52 bits for the mantissa so _only 52_ reorders in the same place before we run out of bits. I suppose you could take the log base 2 of the new middle number and reaches a threshold of say -52 you could re-order the entire table

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

- Iterate over the rows, using an UPDATE statement with a function/etc to generate the updated order value
- Scorched Earth: You delete the existing records, and insert identical ones save the corrected order value

There's no SQL functionality to make this easier, and no real option that is simplistic.

Comment: @Mike Sherov: I loved that game =)

Comment: +1. Although it updates all the rows in the user's orders, it makes for cleanest retrieval and can also prevent concurrency issues. Clever use of clustered indexes can also almost always mean all the updated rows are all on the same page, so the performance penalty of multiple row updates is minimal.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a string in place of a number of infinitely many digits. If you want to insert between "1" and "2" make it a "15".

Comment: You don't. You can append characters infinitely. Between "1" and "15" for example there is "125".

Comment: This seems good. One disadvantage is that with many inserts, the strings in your sort column will grow huge.

Comment: @LynHeadley, I think that it could be ameliorated by using base 64 to take advantage of the vanilla ASCII characters. Admittedly, not an asymptotic solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could instead use a linked list for ordering (with some special way to identify the head).

Insertions are one INSERT and one UPDATE.  Deletions are one DELETE and one UPDATE.  A move is three UPDATEs.  (Use transactions to ensure the linked list doesn't break, of course.)

Comment: Insertions, deletions, and updates are all relatively efficient with a linked list (although the OP didn't even want to do two updates for a swap).  The problem with the linked list is retrieval — for N items you need N SELECTs.

Comment: @Larry Lustig, Yes, but the OP is probably retrieving all the items in the list anyway, and O(N) probably doesn't hurt at all on the client code.

Comment: I see, you're building the linked list in memory after retrieving all the records from the database in a single SELECT.  That is considerably more efficient than what I thought you were recommending — retrieving the rows one at a time in order by checking the Next pointer as you retrieve each row.

Comment: What about pagination? It'd be impossible to query anything with "LIMIT".

Answer (score 1):

Add a DATETIME column called OrderDateTime.  Use this column (in descending order) to resolve "ties" in ordering, and only update it when an ordering operation takes place.

For instance, in your example, assume all the rows have an OrderDateTime value from yesterday.

Now, to insert an item between 1 and 2, you'd set it's Order value to 2 and it's OrderDateTime value to now.  When you SELECT * FROM ProductList ORDER BY Order ASC, OrderDateTime DESC the new number 2 item will sort before the existing one.

Similarly, to swap items 4 and 5, you'd update item 5 to have an order of 4 and an OrderDateTime of now.  It would become a more recent 4 item and appear earlier.

You need to watch out, if you try to insert an item between two other items that already have the same Order value, that you split the OrderDateTime value difference.

Comment: Pretty smart, though it *feels* like a hack.

Comment: Interesting, but I'd rather not be the one to support that.

Comment: I applaud you for the initially clever solution, but your caveat at the end actually is a fatal flaw in the approach. First, DATETIMEs aren't unique. You need a monotonic counter. With that, assume you have `(val, order, counter)` and the tuples `(a, 1, 2)` and `(b, 1, 3)`. You can't insert `c` between `a` and `b`, because there is no way to split the counter difference between 2 and 3 (without updating a, which could cause a cascade of updates). This approach only adds another dimension, which in a way "defers" the problem to another column.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I allow users to reorder the steps in their tour. I have a column called STEP that they can change and I created a column called STEP2. The STEP2 column is automatically updated to the same value as step. But when a user changes STEP, I order by the proposed change and the original order (STEP2) DESC. After the user updates STEP to the new value, I save to the database. Then I run a proc to resequence the steps.

The proc is:

```
DECLARE @t StackTable

INSERT INTO @t(Id)
SELECT Id
FROM TourStops
WHERE TourIdRef = @tourId
ORDER BY [Step], [Step2] DESC

UPDATE TourStops
SET [Step] = t.Position, [Step2] = t.Position
FROM TourStops s join @t t on s.Id = t.Id
```

StackTable is a UDT with 2 columns: Id and Position. Position is an IDENTITY column. Each time it is created it starts with 1 and increments by 1 for each row added.

Comment: My original example did not work. I tried using the TIMESTAMP field along with subquery and i could not get consistent results. I don't know exactly why. Perhaps because changing the values changed the timestamp and therefore reordered the results...? But I had to move the results to a differen table so the order was not changed because of a timestamp change.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Larry Lustig's suggestion of using a double, I've come up with this. Running against a table with 10K rows, it runs pretty fast. Suggestions for improving efficiency are certainly welcome!

```
--- Note:
--- [Order] column is a value type of double
--- when inserting into MyTable, set [Order] to
--- MAX([Order])+10
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MoveUpLevel
(
    @MyTableID int
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON


DECLARE @LevelMe float
DECLARE @LevelMin float
DECLARE @LevelMax float
SELECT @LevelMe = [Order]
    FROM dbo.MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE MyTableID = @MyTableID
SELECT @LevelMin = MIN([Order])
      ,@LevelMax = MAX([Order])
    FROM dbo.MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)

--- Check if already at the top
IF @LevelMe = @LevelMin
    RETURN(0)

DECLARE @LevelAboveMe float
SELECT TOP 1 @LevelAboveMe = [Order]
    FROM dbo.MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [Order] < @LevelMe
    ORDER BY [Order] DESC

DECLARE @LevelAboveMe2 float = 0
IF NOT @LevelAboveMe = @LevelMin
    SELECT TOP 1 @LevelAboveMe2 = [Order]
        FROM dbo.MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE [Order] < @LevelAboveMe
        ORDER BY [Order] DESC

-- calculate new level
SET @LevelMe = @LevelAboveMe2 + ((@LevelAboveMe - @LevelAboveMe2)/2)
-- store to DB
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    SET [Order] = @LevelMe
    WHERE MyTableID = @MyTableID        

RETURN(0)
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MoveDownLevel
(
     @MyTableID int
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @LevelMe float
DECLARE @LevelMin float
DECLARE @LevelMax float
SELECT @LevelMe = [Order]
    FROM dbo.MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE MyTableID = @MyTableID
SELECT @LevelMin = MIN([Order])
      ,@LevelMax = MAX([Order])
    FROM dbo.MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)

--- Check if already at the bottom
IF @LevelMe = @LevelMax
    RETURN(0)

DECLARE @LevelBelowMe float
SELECT TOP 1 @LevelBelowMe = [Order]
    FROM dbo.MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [Order] > @LevelMe
    ORDER BY [Order] ASC

DECLARE @LevelBelowMe2 float = @LevelMax + 10
IF NOT @LevelBelowMe = @LevelMax
    SELECT TOP 1 @LevelBelowMe2 = [Order]
        FROM dbo.MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE [Order] > @LevelBelowMe
        ORDER BY [Order] ASC

-- calculate new level
SET @LevelMe = @LevelBelowMe + ((@LevelBelowMe2 - @LevelBelowMe)/2)

-- store to DB
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    SET [Order] = @LevelMe
    WHERE MyTableID = @MyTableID        

RETURN(0)
END
GO
```