# Best Solution for Querying and Sorting Documents by an User Managed Position?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting, lucene.net

A `User` owns one or many subsets of documents (`Posts`). The idea (UX) is to let the `User` manage (**optionally**) the order in which the `Posts` appears within one subset.

By default, `Posts` are sorted by `CreatedOn`. Eventually, the `User` will **drag-and-drop** `Posts` to manage their order. This would allow the `User` to **promote and organize** its `Posts`.

A simple `Int32` field `Position` raises many questions.. Such as:

- Do you allow a position to be negative?
- How do you handle posts with an identical position?
- Do you introduce gaps to reduce collisions?
- Do you update all posts each time a position changes?
- Etc..

.. and finally my point:

**What is the best solution for sorting Lucene documents by an user managed position?** An `Int32` field `Position` perhaps?

**EDIT** (valuable information):

- Posts are located in a **database and Lucene index**.
- Posts are **paged**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this question: [Reordering an ordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379414/reordering-an-ordered-list)

Sadly, there's no perfect solution to this problem ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest is to emulate a linked list. Add each document a pointer to the next document. If you can't do that directly (you don't actually have addresses, because they are in a database or whatever) you can use IDs and a nextID for each document. Just make sure the IDs are different. When the user will drag-and-drop just rewire the list.

Comment: Posts are indeed located in a database and Lucene index. How do you sort by nextID?

Comment: You don't need to sort by nextID, nextID gives you the ID of the next document in the sorted order. However, this solution is inefficient if you need to show a few documents out of a lot of possible documents. Because you will need to get the documents one by one (each one just has a nextID, not next100IDs). If getting one document at a time is not a problem this works. Another solution is to get all documents from the start and show them based on nextID (linked list order), but this works if you can fit all of them into memory.

Comment: Posts are paged yes. In concerns of scaling I can't afford to load them one by one or mount the subset into memory, unfortunately. I need a strategy that works with a Lucene index.

Comment: However, this is probably the best solution (algorithmic-wise) out there if we omit the database, Lucene and the paged query.

Answer (score 1):

I think `CustomScoreQuery` can be a solution for this

```
public class MyScoreQuery : Lucene.Net.Search.Function.CustomScoreQuery
{
    public MyScoreQuery (Query q) : base(q)
    {
    }
    public override float CustomScore(int doc, float subQueryScore, float valSrcScore)
    {
        //read the doc if you need "indexReader.Document(doc)"
        //and apply your custom logic returning a float
    }
}
```

and the usage could be

```
Query realQuery =  ........
Query q = new MyScoreQuery (realQuery);
```

Comment: Interesting, it'll take me some time to test this out. I'll keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: It is too late to calculate a score relative to other docs in CustomScore. Ideally, I would need to iterate over all docs first, compute a linkedlist and then apply the score in CustomScore. Any idea?

Comment: would it be possible to compute the linkedlist when evaluating the query against the documents, extract it and pass it to the CustomScoreQuery?

Comment: @maxbeaudoin don't make a calculations relative to other docs, that would result in reading too many docs from the index which would result in a very bad performance. To be able to use linked lists or other type of collections means you can load all of the documents to memory, which  eliminates the need for lucene.

Comment: any suggestions on the custom logic necessary to order the doc according to a NextId field?

Comment: @L-B I doubt that this is feasible :(

Comment: @L-B This is probably more an indexing issue than a querying issue.