# Update rankings/priorities at one go in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a personal project in Ruby on Rails in which I have a song model which has a field called priority. A user can add songs to a playlist and set priority to each song, which determines the order in which the songs are played. The problem I am stuck with here, is that I need unique priorities.

So if I have a playlist with 8 songs, and I am adding song number 9 with priority 4, the remaining songs should get their priorities updated. Can any one suggest what is the best way of going about this ?

Comment: This is deceptively painful to implement with a unique constraint on the column. Inserting new rows with a priority is easy, but updating the priority of an existing record not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be able to use the validates_uniqueness_of constraint in the Song model to achieve this?

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :priority, numericality: { only_integer: true }, :uniqueness => {:scope => :playlist_id}

end
```

This should force the user to type in a different number other than the ones already saved for a particular playlist...

Comment: Hi, what you said makes sense, but the whole point is to give the user the flexibility to change priorities at any time - he should be able to play what he wants in the way he wants :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually tasked with a similar problem in my own application.

Here's my first take:

```
class Playlist
  has_many :playlist_songs
  has_many :songs, through: :playlist_songs
end
```

--

```
class PlaylistSong

  before_save :update_priorities, if: :priorities_changed?

  def priorities_changed?
    new_record? || priority_was != priority
  end

  def update_priorities
    if new_record?
      playlist.playlist_songs.update_all("priority = priority+1 where priority >= #{priority}")
    else
      # ouch. not so simple with unique constraint on priority
    end
  end
end
```

The problem with the unique constraint is this:

```
priorities: 1,2,3
update: 3 -> 1

#> triggers

1 -> 2
2 -> 3
```

But 3 is already taken (the current record in which we're changing priority to 1). We cannot change to 1 first because 1 is taken. The only idea I have at the minute is to set the currently updated record to a non-unique priority like 999, but then we're affectively locking updates on the priorities between that query and updating the priority list. I guess you could temporarily set it to a large random number to avoid such unlikely conflicts.

See here for why this is particularly tricky:

[Reordering an ordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379414/reordering-an-ordered-list)

Comment: Thanks for the help !
I have used your suggestion, and modified it a little. I have posted what I have done here, can you take a look at it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I dealt with it - if I enforced a uniqueness constraint, I will have to go with the way Damien has dealt - by assigning some unique priority and then updating. So instead, I decided to let my code deal with the uniqueness. Here's what I have done :

While creating a new song for the playlist, I am calling the `create_new_priorities_for_existing_songs` in the `songs#create` action -

```
def self.create_new_priorities_for_existing_songs (song, priority)
  song_id = song.id
  playlist = song.playlist
  all_songs = playlist.songs
  all_songs.where("priority >= :priority and id != :song_id", :priority => priority, :song_id => song_id).update_all ("priority = priority+1")
end
```

I am calling the `update_priorities_of_existing_songs` method in my `songs#update` action -

```
def self.update_priorities_of_existing_songs (song_id, old_priority, new_priority)
  return if old_priority == new_priority
  song = Song.find(song_id)
  playlist = song.playlist
  all_songs = playlist.songs
  if old_priority < new_priority
    all_songs.where("priority > :old_priority and priority <= :new_priority and id != :song_id", :old_priority => old_priority, :new_priority => new_priority, :song_id => song_id).update_all ("priority = priority-1")
  elsif old_priority > new_priority
    all_songs.where("priority >= :new_priority and priority < :old_priority and id != :song_id", :old_priority => old_priority, :new_priority => new_priority, :song_id => song_id).update_all ("priority = priority+1")
  end
end
```